# Cannot import ephem on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyephem

I'm trying to import pyephem in python on my raspberry pi but I get the following error:

```
pi@ospi ~/downloads/pyephem-3.7.5.3 $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ephem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ephem/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import ephem._libastro as _libastro
ImportError: No module named _libastro
```

I installed the module using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev 
sudo apt-get install python-pip 
sudo pip install pyephem
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `pyephem` is a python interface to `libastro`, that `pip` needs to build using a C compiler on your rasp.  can you confirm that `pip` created and installed the above mentioned library?

Comment: Hmm, any idea how I would confirm this?

Comment: A brute force scheme? `pip uninstall pyephem ; pip install pyephem`

Answer (score 1):

I think my problem was I was out of space on my 8GB SD card. I initially tried to update my pi using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo rpi-update
```

but doing this caused an out of disc space error. I got a 16GB sd card, loaded a saved backup of my system on it. After installing python-dev, python-pip, and pyephem, I could successfully import ephem.

Comment: Great! I am glad that you were able to get it installed. Thanks for sharing this experience — I wish that the install tools would more clearly announce to the user that the install failed because there was no more space on the device.